# IOS 13 Safe area break after switching between landscape and portrait

Tags: orientation, ios13, xcode11, safearealayoutguide

After xcode 11 ios 13 release there were a lot of new bugs in my app: modalPresentationStyle, Facebook SDK and so on. But what really cracked me is that:
In my app i have two windows. One for Unity, one for UIKit client side. I'm switching between them when it needed. Unity window use landscape orientations, client only portrait. The bug happens when i switch to landscape window, minimize and expand back the app and switch back to portrait window. In portrait window the safe area is like for landscape.

I created a project and a video for this bug https://github.com/NikKovIos/IOS13BugWithWindowSafeArea

Tell me if someone has overcome it.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @TarasNikulin Nope( But i sent the bug report to apple.